# Haproxy Balancing. How to find the minimum value in a haproxy checker?

Tags: bash, psql, haproxy

I am trying to configure Haproxy to balance between postgres replicas. 
The main task: the request should be redirected to the node with the most current data.
Check data relevance runs on master_node:

```
select client_addr AS client, (pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn))::int / 1024 as total_lag from pg_stat_replication;
```

With this command, I get a list of hosts and replication_lag.
For example:

```
111.111.111.111 | 152
222.222.222.222 | 9
333.333.333.333 | 4700
```

I need a host with a minimum value.
I do not understand three things:

1. How do I pass a replica name to a custom haproxy_checker?
2. How do I compare the values ​​obtained?
3. How to specify haproxy based on the given values ​​to which of the replicas to switch requests to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied these settings:
**haproxy.cfg**

```
lua-load /etc/haproxy/scripts/choosebackend.lua

frontend psql-front
bind *:5432
mode tcp
use_backend %[lua.choose_backend]

backend backend1
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
server pg1 111.111.111.111:5432 check port 5432

backend backend2
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
server pg2 222.222.222.222:5432 check port 5432
```

**choosebackend.lua**

```
luasql = require "luasql.postgres"
env = luasql.postgres()
con = assert (env:connect('postgres', 'postgres', 'postgres','333.333.333.333','5432')) --master

backend = function(txn)
res = assert (con:execute('select client_addr from pg_stat_replication order by replay_lag asc limit 1'))
row = res:fetch ({}, "a")
while row do
        ip = string.format("%-12s", row.client_addr)
        row = res:fetch (row, "a")
end
result = "backend1"
if ip == '111.111.111.111' then
result = "backend1"
elseif ip == '222.222.222.222' then
result = "backend2"
end
return result
end

core.register_fetches("choose_backend", backend)
```

Haproxy must be compiled from source, because by default LUA support is disabled in it. Additionally, you need to install **luarocks** and **luasql-postgres**

Comment: In haproxy version 2.2. and above, Lua support is already included and it makes no sense to install it from source.